# How can I read in a file and output certain lines of the files into another text file, and how do I add additional files?

Tags: python, file-io

I have a file called tclust.txt, and another named ef_blue.xpk. I want to read in lines from ef_blue.xpk, and output it to tclust.txt. Currently I have this line of code

```
import re
import sys 
import os 

lines = open('tclust.txt').readlines()
last_line = lines[-1] 

open ('tclust.txt','w').writelines(lines[:-2])

with open("ef_blue.xpl","rt") as f1, open("tclust.txt","a") as f2:
    for line in f1.readlines():
        float_num = re.findall("[\s][1-9]{1}\.[0-9]+",line)
        if len(float_num)>1:
            f2.writelines(' '*6 +float_num[0] + '0.05' + float_num[1] + '0.05' + '\n')
 f2.writelines(last_line)
```

[This is an image of my tclust.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAAzf.png)

[This is an image of my ef_blue.xpk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVH3I.png)

[This is what I would want my tclust.txt file to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjN79.png)

[This is what I actually get as my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70AeJ.png)

And if I wanted to read in another file, for example, ee_blue.xpk which looks like this [ef_green.xpk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPNK8.png) how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code like this:

```
import re

lines = open('tclust.txt').readlines()
last_line = lines[-1]

open ('tclust.txt', 'w').writelines(lines[:-2])

with open("ef_blue.xpl", "rt") as f1, open("tclust.txt","a") as f2:
    iValue = 0
    for line in f1.readlines():
        float_num = re.findall("[\s][1-9]{1}\.[0-9]+", line)
        if len(float_num) > 1:
            lineValue = "Peak {0} {1} {2} {3} {4}\n".format(iValue, float_num[0], "0.05", float_num[1], "0.05")
            f2.writelines(lineValue)
            iValue += 1
f2.writelines(last_line)
```

Comment: That gave me an output of just "Peak" 
I'll edit my question with a picture

Comment: When just show the `Peak`, the `float_num` value is length than 1, so please change the judge condition `if len(float_num) > 1:`

Comment: what do I change it to?

Comment: You can try get the length  of `float_num`, user the `print(len(float_num ))`, and see the output values , and than choose a value replaced the `1` in the `if len(float_num) > 1:`